# Creating a Feynman loop diagram with feynmf

Tags: feynmf

I try to draw this Feynman diagram with `feynmf` in `LaTeX`:

[image: Feynman diagram wanted to draw]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{fmffile}{edm_neutrino}    
\begin{fmfchar*}(50,40)
\fmfkeep{vlm1}
\fmfleft{o}\fmflabel{$\nu_\tau$}{o}
\fmfright{i}\fmflabel{$\nu_\tau$}{i}
\fmftop{g}\fmflabel{$\gamma_\mu$}{g}
\fmf{plain, tension=1.5}{i,v1} \fmflabel{$Y_{ib}$}{v1}
\fmf{phantom, label=$\tau_j$, tension=0.8, left=1.0,tag=1}{v2,v1}
\fmf{dashes_arrow, label=$W^+$, left=-1.0, tension=0.4}{v2,v1}
\fmf{plain, tension=2.5}{v2,o}
\fmfposition
\fmfipath{p[]}
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath1(__v2,__v1)}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (0,2length(p1)/3) of p1}
\fmfi{fermion}{subpath (2length(p1)/3,length(p1)) of p1}
\fmfi{photon}{point length(p1)/3 of p1 -- point 2length(p1)/3 of p1}
%should go to g
\end{fmfchar*}

\end{fmffile}
```

But I don't know how to connect the point on the `W^-` line to the external point `g`. Is there any possibility to write something like that?

```
 \fmfi{photon}{point 2length(p1)/3 of p1 -- point g}
```

This line is not correct, I know. But how to fix?

Thank you very much for reading!
matthias

Answer (score 2):

You are beyond the powers of the `feynmf` automatic layout routine so you need to use "immediate" mode to place your nodes.

However at that point, it usually become easier to draw the diagram directly in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), using the `feynmp` macros.  Like this:

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
input feynmp;
beginfig(1);

path ring; ring = fullcircle scaled 78;
z1 = -z2 = 78 left; z3 = z2 rotated -24;

label.top(btex $\tau_j$ etex, point 2 of ring);
label.bot(btex $W^+$    etex, point 6 of ring);
label.top(btex $\nu_\tau$ etex, z1);
label.top(btex $\nu_\tau$ etex, z2);
label.rt(btex $\gamma_\mu$ etex, z3);

draw fermion z1 -- point 4 of ring;
draw fermion subpath(4,0) of ring;
draw fermion point 0 of ring -- z2;
draw_dashes_arrow subpath(4,8) of ring;
draw photon origin -- z3 cutbefore ring;

endfig;
end.
```

(Note that a `fullcircle` path has 8 points on it running anticlockwise from the 3 o'clock position.)

The interface is quite neat: `feynmp` defines a number of macros as path decorators, that take a path as the right argument and return a decorated path.  For example `fermion` above. Unfortunately the set of decorators is not quite complete, so for the dashed arrow we have to call the `draw_dashes_arrow` macro directly.  The only documentation that I've ever found is the Metapost source file, but `fmfman.pdf` is still useful.